# How can I blank out the background of the key in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

My plot is covering up my key in gnuplot. What I'm plotting oscillates a lot, so there's nowhere on my plot I can go and not interfere with something. How can I give the key an opaque background so that the items inside aren't covered up by lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My version of gnuplot supports opaque keys via:

```
 set key opaque
```

Try out the following:

```
 set key box opaque
 plot sin(x)
```

---

Another option in cases like these is to move the key outside the plotting area:

```
set key outside
plot sin(x)
```

This way you don't obscure any of your valuable data.

Comment: Unfortunately my version of gnuplot does not support `set key opaque`.

Comment: @Dan -- What version of gnuplot are you using?  I'm at gnuplot 4.6.1